# loopback: timeout when I try to get another user of another principalType

Tags: timeout, loopback

I have implemented multiple user models by following official guide on http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Authentication-authorization-and-permissions.html#access-control-with-multiple-user-models

I have 3 user types

1. Admin (principalType = AdminUser)
2. Moderator (principalType = ModeratorUser)
3. Customer (principalType = CustomerUser)

Similarly, I have 3 models defined

1. AdminUser
2. ModeratorUser
3. CustomerUser

I have also defined a **CustomAccessToken** as per above guide. Everything seems to be working fine. The only issue occurs when I try to get single Customer when I am logged in as Admin.

http://localhost:3000/api/customer-users/:id (Timeout always, if I am accessing it as Admin. But it works fine when accessing as Customer)

Listing of customers works fine. It looks like some ACL issue, I tried with $everyone also.. but still, it didn't work. The request is timing out always.

Answer (score 0):

Thank God, I found the solution to my problem. Please follow https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/3883 to resolve the issue.

**EDIT**

The fix is in the loopback 3.19.1 So, please update and it will resolve the Owner role issue.